# Android Webview on top of MediaPlayer

Tags: android, webview, media-player

I am creating a website that uses a webview that can start a MediaPlayer instance and stream content. During playback I have HTML elements to controls start/stop etc.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to make this work. What I would like is for the video to be behind the webview such that I can see a video play whilst HTML objects are on the screen at the same time.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow! It might be useful to others if you also posted a little bit of code just to fully describe your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand what exactly you want. to control the order of views in a layout use `View.bringToFront()`. and to make a view transparent use `View.setAlpha(0)`.

Comment: Thanks Rotem. I tried that with little success. Not sure if after reading your comment and the one by Parriss above that my original ask was clear. What I would like is for the MediaPlayer to be transparent such that I can use a webview on top of it. The webview has a body element set to transparent.

Comment: please show your layout file. you should use a FrameLayout: put a VideoView and above it your WebView. but why wouldn't you create native android controllers for your video? your solution sounds like a bad idea because it will be impossible to fit the buttons on the rights places for all kind of resolutions and screen sizes.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/canvas"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    />
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    />
</FrameLayout>

Comment: Agh. Need to figure out how to style code on here. I only care about a specific resolution hence this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was that there is a bug in Android that prevents content from being seen behind a webview whilst hardware acceleration is enabled.

Bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14749

Workaround: Enable hardware acceleration when content beneath video is not needed, and disable when it is.